# swip horizontal and vertical listview items

Tags: android, listview, layout, swipe

my application looks transportation routes and the results need to be displayed on the bottom of the layout in a horizontal listview and also to slide up detail can be seen that content.

Here a picture. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this lib will help you, it has the swipe, drag and expand functionalities:

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview